# How to add show/hide in navigation setting for pages

Tags: navigation

I'd like to add a checkbox for each page's edit page that decides whether or not that page shows up in navigation. How can I achieve something like that in WordPress?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the custom menu function not address your needs? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [exclude pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/exclude-pages/) plugin. If you activate this plugin, then on each page you find a checkbox with:
**Include this page in lists of pages**.

If you uncheck it, the page is not shown in your navigation.